# Flutter ios and statusbar text color

Tags: flutter

I read dozens of questions and answers, I read a lot of articles and tried a lot of things, I can't get the status bar text of my app to be  white on ios. so first here's a screen shot. [image]

I obviously want it white. Here is what I tried :

1. I first tried using the theme of my CuppertinoApp, especially the brightness property
2. I tried using `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle` to set the statusBrightness
3. I tried using the `Info.plist` of my app to set the brightness, and it worked, as in, it is white during the loading, but then, it becomes black when the app really starts.
4. I tried this package : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor and it works too for about 0,2 second, I see the text being white, and then black again.

Every test I did, I used both brightness settings to avoid any misunderstanding and every time I completely refreshed the whole app to avoid any cache problem. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there's no other answer than this :

[How can i change status text bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571241/how-can-i-change-status-text-bar-color/56582874#56582874)

I'll let people appreciate the time Hugo Passos spent documenting it.

Answer (score 4):

To make the text and icons white on the status bar use the below code anywhere in your code, ideally in main or in one of the top level widget's build.

```
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark)
  );
```

Then re-run your app just incase to see the changes.

p.s: To make the icons dark again use `Brightness.light`

Comment: well in fact, I didn't see it, but it does the same as 3) and 4), it's white for a very short time (~0.1 second) and then it's black. I think the problem is from the CupertinoNavigationBar, If I remove it, then all the methods work like a charm. but I kinda need navigation. If I set the navigationbar background color to black, it works and I have white text ont he status bar, but I need it pinkish like in my screen.

Comment: @moo Well, you're right. `CupertinoNavigationBar` overrides the status bar style based on the color you set. E.g if you use dark background it makes the text and icons white etc. This is not ideal of course.