# How can i change status text bar color

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm trying put the status bar text color in Brightness Light, with CupertinoNavigationBar

I already tried put in the main the SystemUiOverlayStyle with statusBarColor and the brightness, but not works
[That text in status bar need be white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ssom.png)

```dart
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
    statusBarColor: Colors.white,
    statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light
  ));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I'm trying create the appbar for ios and android, but i want put the status bar text color Light, i put a condition which is if is ios i create the CupertinoNavigationBar() and if is android i put the normal AppBar(), if is just the AppBar with brightness, he works fine, but with CupertinoNavigationBar(), no

Comment: What problem are you facing? When using `CupertinoNavigationBar`, your status bar should be light automatically.

Comment: My background color in CupertinoNavigationBar is 0xFF81d8d0, and this is a blue/green and the status bar its black, but i dont want black, i want white

Comment: i put a image on post, look at

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

Now `CupertinoNavigationBar` also has a `brightness` property.

## Old answer

It's not possible to do that.

`CupertinoNavigationBar` uses the method [`_wrapWithBackground()`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c2a93bd545205666abb260d7b41ee337359b3a57/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart#L85) to define whether the status bar is going to be light or dark, so the setting you made with `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle()` is never going to be considered.

A typical solution would be creating your own navigation bar extending `CupertinoNavigationBar`, but this is not easy to do in such situation, since `CupertinoNavigationBar` has a private `State` and calls other private classes and methods.

In fact, `CupertinoNavigationBar` is poorly designed if you compare to `AppBar`, which considers three attributes to define its brightness:

1. `brightness` argument that can be passed through the constructor;
2. `ThemeData.AppBarTheme.brightness`;
3. `ThemeData.primaryColorBrightness`.

Notice that there's an attribute to specify the brightness of Cupertino Widgets, which is `CupertinoThemeData.brightness`, but it is (oddly) not considered inside `_wrapWithBackground()`.

There's an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30114) about this already. You should wait for Flutter team response, but until then you can use [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30114#issuecomment-508144393) workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the brightness to dark. In the AppBar, if I set the Brightness to light, it will make the status bar text to black.

```
statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
```

Comment: i put that but, works when i use just app bar, to ios and to android, but if i put if to ios and use cupertinoNavigation, he doesn't works

Comment: I just checked the CupertinoNavigationBar and it appears to change the status bar color based on the backgroundColor. I tried this: 

CupertinoNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black24,
      )  and it changed the status text to white.

Comment: yes he changed, but, the appbar need to be the 0xFF81d8d0, and the contrast for this color is black, but the black is so ugly with this color

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41067#issuecomment-571689955
(iOS Dark Mode and Android)

Add line in **Info.plist**

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<true/>
```

And change status bar

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
/// ...
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light) // Or Brightness.dark
);
```